# В табличной верстке нельзя использовать display: block?

Tags: html, css

В табличной верстке нельзя использовать display: block?

Comment: можно, но зачем?

Answer (score 2):

Как поменять пол человеку. Можно, но родсвенные элементы будут страдать и вести себя не адекватно

Answer (score 0):

Можно, ровно так же как и в блочной `display: table`.
Но у двух этих CSS правил и HTML элементов изначально разные задачи:

**`display: block;`**

> Элемент показывается как блочный. Применение этого значения для встроенных элементов, например тега `<span>`, заставляет его вести подобно блокам — происходит перенос строк в начале и в конце содержимого.

**`<div>`**

> Элемент `<div>` является блочным элементом и предназначен для выделения фрагмента документа с целью изменения вида содержимого.

**`display: table;`**

> Определяет, что элемент является блочной таблицей подобно использованию тега `<table>`.

**`<table>`**

> Элемент  служит контейнером для элементов, определяющих содержимое таблицы. Любая таблица состоит из строк и ячеек, которые задаются с помощью тегов `<tr>` и `<td>`.

Источники: [display](https://htmlbook.ru/css/display), [тег <div>](https://htmlbook.ru/html/div), [тег <table>](https://htmlbook.ru/html/table)